# Creating a Video for DVD

Tags: video

Sorry if there is an obvious answer to this question; I haven't done any video editing ever so I'm struggling with something; How should I set up my output and encoding preferences?

I was tasked with cutting and merging different video files for my brother; he wants to create a DVD with some old family footage. I've already have all the audio and video strips set up the way I want them to playback. I'm just having issues figuring out what file format will work on a writable DVD disc.

Also, I want the quality to remain relatively high (as high as possible since the footage is already sorta bad from being a bit old).

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about DVD mastering try http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: while it is possible to edit and encode mpeg2 video files in blender, a playable DVD requires files to be in a a very specific compression format and file structure (like VOB, Ifos, Bup, etc and other files. Look on the internet for software for DVD authoring, there are quite a lot of them.

Answer (score 4):

The two standards for DVDs are [NSTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC) or [PAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL). Both are a rather low quality format by today's HD standards. You said that you are coming from old media, so going to DVD there will be no loss in quality.

Blender makes it quite easy with presets. Here I'm assuming NSTC.
Everything you need to set is in the Render tab of the properties window.
There is a preset for the dimensions: *TV NTSC*. The preset for the output is split among two headings *Output* and *Encoding*. Choose *MPEG* for the file type, and make sure it is set to *RGB*. Then the default *DVD* preset for the encoding works well.
[image: render settings]